# Not Able to get request body as desired

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am working on MERN stack and I have made an api for registering users. I am using axios to send request this is what i am doing with axios inside react

```
const body = {
            'phone': phoneData.phoneNumber, \\ phoneData is a state 
            'lastName': 'Flintstone'
        }
        await axios({
                method : 'post',
                url : 'http://localhost:8000/userapi/register',
                data : JSON.stringify(body),
                header : {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
            });
```

After this in NodeJS i am trying to print `req.body` on the console an this is what i am receiving

```
{ '{"phone":"7428868740","lastName":"Flintstone"}': '' }
```

instead of that i want `req.body` to store

```
{ phone:"7428868740",lastName:"Flintstone" }
```

This is my route that is getting triggered

```
app.post('/userapi/register', (req,res) =>{
      console.log(req.body);
      /*  rest code to register user  */
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `Axios`, you don't need to call `JSON.stringify`, just send the object and the server will receive it correctly.

```
    const body = {
            'phone': phoneData.phoneNumber, // phoneData is a state 
            'lastName': 'Flintstone'
    }

    await axios({
                method : 'post',
                url : 'http://localhost:8000/userapi/register',
                data : body,
                headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
            });
```

See documentation [here](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosconfig)

On the server-side, make sure there is a middleware to parse requests in JSON format.

Comment: I am receiving an empty object in the console now ```{}```

I am using ```app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}))```
Can you tell me more about middleware to parse requests in JSON format.

Comment: Thanks I got it i need to use ```app.use(express.json())```

Answer (score 0):

You can

```
const config = {
        header: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      };
const res = await axios.post(url,body,config)
```

Comment: I am receiving an empty object in the console now ```{}```